# Can not mount NFS disk to Linux Machine

Tags: linux, nfs

I am trying to mount a nfs disk to red-hat 7.4 server but it hangs.

And I also tried to change the type to nfs to nfs4 it did not work.

Could you help me?

dmesg output;

```
      nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache
      [4928885.501390] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period (net 
      ffffffff81ad9d40)

      IP:/sharenfs /sharenfs     nfs       rw                0 0
```

service output;

```
      service nfs status

       Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status nfs.service
       ● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
        Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; 
        disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: active (exited) since Wed 2018-03-14 12:17:15 +03; 23min ago
```

ping output;

```
        ping sharenfs
        3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss
```

hosts.allow is empty

Comment: What OS is the NFS server running? Also, post the output of [`showmount -e sharenfs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/showmount.8.html), assuming `sharenfs` is the hostname of the NFS server.

Comment: Please post content of `/etc/exports` file from NFS server. Does it allow your client machine to connect to the server? What is the error message on client device when you try to `mount` from command line?

Comment: An easy way to rule out truly server side issues is to mount your NFS export locally on the NFS server. Beyond that, NFS issues almost always boil down to permissions, firewalls, or network issues of some kind.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how i'd try to troobleshoot your problem :

- You cannot ping `sharenfs`, so either it is not well setup in your DNS, or is not in your `/etc/host` file, or your firewall is blocking your packets. Anyway, your server does not know to which IP address send its requests. This means that at this moment the communication between your RedHat and your nfs is not possible (at least using the name of your nfs share, try to ping the IP if your sure that your NFS work properly)
- `Active: active (exited)` means that your nfs service is running but systemd does not know there is a daemon to monitor. If there is one, you must define it in the unit file by configuring the Type and ExecStart options appropriately according to whether the process you start is the main proces, forks child processes and exits etc (man pages are your friend here). Services files are usually on `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` directory. My advice, before make any modification to the service file make a local backup of the file in case you need to return to the previous state)

Once you've solved this two problems I think you'll see it more clairly

Cheers

Comment: Neither of those points answer this problem, as OP CAN contact nfsshare by name and systemd monitoring a service has nothing to do with the functionality of the service itself.

Comment: Please read first point. If no communication is possible between your servers is nothing that you can do, ie, you'll not be able to contact your NFS server. Solve this problem first and try after

Comment: Agree that the second point is not very useful to solve your problem, but is the correct way to do things, you should always try to apply the best practices. After you can do as you wish, is just an advice

Comment: You have asserted that sharenfs cannot be pinged successfully. Re-read the question, as this is not the case.

Comment: my bad, I was doing two things at the same time and read to quickly

Comment: You can try this : [possible solution 1](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/nfs4-mount-nfs4-access-denied-by-server-while-mounting-848430/) or this : [possible solution 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32520/nfs-keeps-randomly-crashing-breaks-mount-on-other-clients)

Comment: By the way, If you want more accurate solutions, you can maybe post your configuration settings.

Comment: Thank's for the **-1** mate, next time I'll think it twice before try to help you :-)

Comment: I downvoted you, which is why I explained my downvote in a comment.

Comment: No problem and good luck !